# What if I know for sure that my target variable is not normally but Beta distributed?

Tags: modeling, beta-distribution

As stated in the question, what sort of modeling technique would be most appropriate?

Comment: Wikipedia for [the beta distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) provides a ready-made formula for parameter estimation if you simply want to fit a beta distribution to a variable. In a regression setting, the answer is more complicated.

Comment: @user333 if you can give more information about your data, it would help us more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[beta regression](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v34/i02/paper): see Fransisco Cribari-Neto and Achim Zeileis, "Beta Regression in R", Journal of Statistical Software, volume 34, issue 2, April 2010.  If you have linear regression problem with a Beta noise process, then this is the neat solution.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the suggestions, you could also try the *logit* transformation:

$$\log \frac{p}{1-p}$$

where $p$ is a Beta random variable.

You can now fit a linear regression model. The estimates would be ok, the only thing that might be a problem are inferences regarding the regression coefficients.

In order to avoid this problem, I would choose Bayesian approaches that impose a diffuse t-prior on the regression coefficients. If you don't have a huge data set, you could try either the **[bayesglm](http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/arm/html/bayesglm.html)** function in the **arm** package or fit a hierarchical model using **JAGS** and **rjags** package in R. Otherwise if you have a huge data set, normal Gaussian regression should work fine.

However, I must remark that the choice depends on the specific data that you have and the interpretation of the parameter estimates.